# Сдвиг массива k раз

Tags: javascript

Левым сдвигом массива мы назывем то действие, во время которого каждый элемент массива одним шагом сдвигается налево, но в массиве каличество элементов остается неизменным.
Надо написать функцию, который как параметр получает массив A и возвращает массив, который получится когда мы массив А сдвинем налево k раз. Где k = min[A].

```js
function moveLeft(x) {
  let k = Math.min(...x)
  return x = x.concat(x.splice(0, x.length - k));
}

console.log(moveLeft([2, 3, 7, 8]));
// Должен выводится [7, 8, 2, 3]
console.log(moveLeft([10, 2, 3, 1]));
// Должен выводится [2, 3, 1, 10]
console.log(moveLeft([4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4]));
// Должен выводится [6, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
console.log(moveLeft([5]));
// Должен выводится [5]
console.log(moveLeft([-1, -2, 1, 4]));
// Должен выводится [-2, 1, 4, -1]
console.log(moveLeft([-1, -4, -5]));
// Должен выводится [-1, -4, -5]
```

В первом случае я получаю верный ответ, но в других лучиях код коректно не работает. Помогите пожолуйста найти мою ощибку и решить задачу

Comment: непонятно почему для `[-1, -4, -5]` результат должен быть такой же, а для `[-1, -2, 1, 4]` сдвиг влево на 1, а не на 2, минимальное же значение -2

Comment: либо задача дана некорректная, либо примеры :) судя по примерам, минимальное должно искаться только среди положительных элементов, но в самой задаче этого не указано.

Comment: Почему именно так? :) об этом есть что-то в задаче?:) или ты пытаешься вывести что-то по примерам? Где вообще проверяешь?

Comment: Верно говоря я тоже вполне не понял. Да вы правы, я просто хотел вивести по примерам чтобы совпало. Это из задачника. Там есть тесты чтобы проверить правильно решил задачу или нет.

Comment: Что за задачник?

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка в неверном параметре для функции [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Достаточно передать сам найденный элемент. Плюс, для случая, когда значение может быть больше длинны массива лучше взять остаток от деления на длину.

```js
function moveLeft(x) {
  let k = Math.min(...x) % x.length;
  return x = x.concat(x.splice(0, k));
}

console.log(moveLeft([2, 3, 7, 8]));
// Должен выводится [7, 8, 2, 3]
console.log(moveLeft([10, 2, 3, 1]));
// Должен выводится [2, 3, 1, 10]
console.log(moveLeft([4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4]));
// Должен выводится [6, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

Comment: К сожелению в этом случае не работает

Comment: @Georg, что именно не работает? Неверные ответы в сниппете?

Comment: function moveLeft(x) {
    let k = Math.min(...x) % x.length;
    return x = x.concat(x.splice(0, k));
  }

console.log(moveLeft([-1,-2,1,4]));   // Должен выводится [-2,1,4,-1]

Comment: @Georg, :-D добавь этот пример в вопрос, чтобы было видно, что значения могут быть не только положительными :) И плюсом, логику работы с отрицательным минимальным, непонятно почему именно такой ответ должен выводиться

Comment: Да сейчас немедленно добавлю